# Android receives GPS Fix when called with getLastKnownLocation but not when called without it

Tags: android, gps

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener
{

  private Location l;
  private Location x;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LocationManager provider = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    l = provider.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    showm();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date(l.getTime());

    Toast.makeText(this, "Fix received on: " + format.format(date), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  void showm()
  {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude: " + l.getLatitude() + ", Longitude: " + l.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
  {
    if(location != null)
      x = location;
  }
```

Now this code works if I run the app the LocationListener method is invoked and GPS fix is received now right after that I call `provider.getLastKnownLocation` and according to the Date from Second Toast I got the current location and the showm() method will show a toast with correct Long/Latitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

showm() should be inside onLocationChanged(Location location).

you are trying to show the location while the query is still in progress. On GPS fix a new location is reported via callback onLocationChanged(...) method. else a NULL(which is the reason for null exception).

Comment: Ok tried and it worked but how about if I would need the location that onLocationChanged() method received outside the method I assign it to private Location l; but when I call Location l inside onCreate() method it throws a null exception.

Comment: are you sure the location object and l after assignment are same when you call insde onCreate()?

Comment: Hey mate thanks a lot you really helped me solve the annoying part of the problem. There was some problems with accessing Location l in onCreate so I simply moved Location tracking to new class and implemented Observer-Observable between two classed and then when onLocationChanged is called I use setChanged() and notifyObservers(location) to get the Location object to Main activity.